# How to run container with privileged flags using KubernetesPodOperator in GoogleCloudComposer?

Tags: google-cloud-composer, gcsfuse

I need to use a container with `gcsfuse` in google cloud composer, as far as i know `--privileged` flags when running the container is needed for `gcsfuse`, how to use `--privileged` flags when running the container using `kubernetes` pod operator in google cloud composer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [KubernetesPodOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/kubernetes_pod_operator.py) and its internal [implementation](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/kubernetes/pod.py), I don't think securityContext is exposed and configurable. You may want to file an [Apache Airflow JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/AIRFLOW/issues) issue for feature tracking.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i'm currently using python google cloud storage module to compensate it